# How to upload SQL database in hosting?

Tags: php, sql, hosting

I'm new to website hosting. 
I had successfully uploaded the files, now I want to upload database, can anybody help me to upload database from my localhost to my hosting website.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh: Database is not **exploded** its **exported** ..

Comment: Sorry my mistake. try to export your database and import it on your server database. After successful import change database configuration in the file where it written(connection code of database)

Answer (score 2):

Use following step:

1. Go to cpanel.
2. create database by going to database option in cpanel.
3. assign db user to that database.
4. now go to that phpmyadmin.
5. export local db.
6. now import on live db.
7. Set home url and site url in option table.

work is done.

Answer (score 1):

Generally all hosting services offer PhpMyAdmin. You can save your localhost database as local .sql file and import it on the server database.

PhpMyAdmin takes care of adding the commands to create the tables, so it is pretty easy.

You can find more details in the PhpMyAdmin docs.